# Expand LazyVStack display area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `ScrollView` composed by views whose content is loaded asynchronously. The elements can be ideally infinite so I decided to wrap them in `LazyVStack`.
The problem is that the async content takes some times to load so when scrolled it appears after some time. I would like to start their loading a little before. Exist a way to make `LazyVStack` thinks the displayed view is a little larger?

```swift
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        ForEach(modelURLs) { modelURL in
            AsyncModel(url: modelURL)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you meant by *a little larger*? ... by comparing to what/which? Doesn't some padding work for this?

Comment: @Asperi what he means, you know lazystack doesn't reload until you scroll to that part. He wants to trick the screen to make it think that you already scrolled by that the data will be reloaded before you scroll. I'm wondering if you can do such thing.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that worked in my specific case, I hope in a better one:

```swift
struct ModelList: View {
    
    let models: [ModelURLs]
    
    private let preloadingPadding: CGFloat = 300  // !!!
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(modelURLs) { modelURL in
                    AsyncModel(url: modelURL)
                }
            }.padding(preloadingPadding) // !!!
        }.padding(-preloadingPadding) // !!!
    }
}
```